# How do we know if python code is in never ending loop in c or c++?

Tags: python, c++

I am embedding Python interpreter in C/C++ code. If the python code is in never-ending loop, it is possible to say the application crashes because you can not terminate the c++ code. So My question is how do I know if the python code is in a never-ending loop so that I can return the execution of the code back to c++ side?

Comment: Please avoid the phrase "C/C++". There is not such language as "C/C++", only the distinct and very different languages C and C++. And if you're programming in C++, then there's really no need to mention C at all.

Comment: That's one of the biggest NP-hard problems in computing theory. It's called Halting Problem. More about that here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Since I've faced a similar problem, I can empathize with your situation. All you need to do is allocate virtual stack space to check if something has run into infinite recursion. In general infinite loop has no solution to detect, unless you choose to manually allocate maximum time to obtain results.

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMARDESAI it's not *hard*, it's *undecidable* in general.

Comment: @Caleth it's undecidable only for infinite machine, for finite machine it's decidable. Quote from wiki: "The halting problem is theoretically decidable for linear bounded automata (LBAs) or deterministic machines with finite memory."

Comment: @sklott yes, but you need a(n absurdly) bigger machine to do the determination

Comment: I think nobody understands the question. all the above comments are irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

In general, it is not possible to predict whether some piece of code is going to run forever. This is known as the undecidability of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).
Now you might detect problems in some "trivial cases" but even a simple loop that seems nice enough can be tricky. Consider the following piece of code:

```
def syracuse(n):
  while(n != 1):
    if(n % 2 == 0):
      n = n/2
    else:
      n = 3*n+1
  return True
```

Will this return for every n>0? If you are able to answer this you will have proven the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), which is a long standing problem in mathematics.

The best thing I can suggest is to stop the execution of the Python code based on some arbitrary time threshold which you consider to be reasonable.

Comment: Very nice answer, the Collatz Conjecture is a great example! (I would phrase it as "every n>0" though to avoid ambiguity).